# How to create a * box in python through nested loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a *box through nested loop. So How I can create box?

I've tried to create a logic through some division, multiplication, subtraction, modules.I don't what is problem?

```
for colm in range(1,5):
    print('* ',end='')
    for row in range(1,21):
        if (colm==1) or (colm==4) or (row==20  and colm==2) or (row==20 and colm==3) :
            print('*',end=' ')
    print('')
```

**Output:**

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * 
* * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

**I expected:**

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
*                                       *  <---- I want * here.
*                                       *  <---- I want * here.
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: Where's the `else` to print spaces inside the box??

Answer (score 2):

```
rows = 5
cols = 23
for i in range(rows):
    print('*' + ('*' if i in (0,rows-1) else ' ') * (cols-2) + '*')
```

output

```
***********************
*                     *
*                     *
*                     *
***********************
```

All rows start and end with an asterisk, and only the top and bottom fill, the middle rows all use spaces instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fill in the missing space with something - your writing cursor is always after the last character, it doesn't magically move sideways.

Also, you can use replicating strings instead of the inner loop to get rid of `if`s:

```
print("*" * columns)
for row_no in range(rows-2): # -2 because we print top and bottom row differently
    print("*" + " "*(columns-2) + "*")

print("*" * columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def print_rectangle(n, m) : 

    for i in range(1, n+1) : 
        for j in range(1, m+1) : 
            if (i == 1 or i == n or
                j == 1 or j == m) : 
                print("*", end="")             
            else : 
                print(" ", end="")             

        print() 


# Driver program for above function 
rows = 6 # Breadth of your Quadrilateral
columns = 20 #Length of your Quadrilateral
print_rectangle(rows, columns)
```

The driver part of the program can be `run-time` based if you want, to do that you need to take `integer` input from the user.

```
rows= int(input("Enter the breadth of your Quadrilateral"))
```

Now let's understand what happens when you call the `print_rectangle(rows, columns)`

The part that you need to understand is this

```
for i in range(1, n+1) : 
            for j in range(1, m+1) : 
                if (i == 1 or i == n or
                    j == 1 or j == m) : 
                    print("*", end="")             
                else : 
                    print(" ", end="")
```

In simple language, *if you observe the structure you want it to have `*` if it is the **1st column** or the **nth column** `OR` if it the **1st row** or the **nth row***

So the outer loop takes care of columns

```
 for i in range(1, n+1)
```

and the inner loop takes care of the number of rows.

```
for j in range(1, m+1)
```

Now you must relate the variable `i` with `row-number` and `j` with `column-number` and then read the `if clause`.*You will find it says the same thing I explained above in terms of English words*.

If you need further clarification, I'll be happy to elaborate it for you if you let me know where you are having trouble.

Comment: Can I have understand?

Comment: @mishsx is adding white spaces just as I suggested, his code is doing the same as my edit of yours ;)

Comment: @Nils Perhaps he need a walkthrough, although you suggested that, he could not comprehend it better. Nevertheless, your help is still appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple algorithm to print box shapes

1. Define the length and breadth of the box(rows and columns).
2. Loop through rows and columns
3. For row

   - If the row item(i in our case is i==0 or i==row, then print **'*'** except print **space**.
   - this will print our left and right side of the box.
4. For columns

   - If the columns item(j in our case is j==0 or j==columns, then print **'*'** except print **space**.
   - this will print our top and bottom side of box.

Note: we used `**end=''**` to prevent newline after printing **'*'** or **space**

```
def box(rows, columns):
    for i in range(1, rows + 1):
        for j in range(1, columns + 1):
            if (i == 1 or i == rows or j == 1 or j == columns):
                print('*', end='  ')
            else:
                print(' ', end='  ')
        print()
```

## square

```
>>> box(10,10)
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  
*                          *  
*                          *  
*                          *  
*                          *  
*                          *  
*                          *  
*                          *  
*                          *  
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
```

## rectangle

```
>>> box(10,5)
*  *  *  *  *  
*           *  
*           *  
*           *  
*           *  
*           *  
*           *  
*           *  
*           *  
*  *  *  *  *
```